# Magento shop static block with different content in shops

Tags: magento, static-block

so as you read title, i need help with magento static block, my task is to make static block content different in 2 shops, if it's even possible? ty for answers.
P.S. Sorry for bad english.

Comment: is this in a multi store set up or 2 completely separate websites?

Comment: multi store set up, it worked with mac444s answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one it works for me. I made it with html/javascript. You can get store name by

```
var shopName= '{{config path="general/store_information/name"}}';
```

and then compare by your needs. Paste code into static block editor.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="websiteMessage()">  
<p>Happy new years !!!</p>  
<p id="static_block"></p>

<script>
function websiteMessage() {
    var shopName= '{{config path="general/store_information/name"}}';
    var string = "";

if(shopName.localeCompare("Leather_shoes_shop") == 0)
{
    string = "leather shoes";
} 
else if(shopName.localeCompare("Rubber_shoes_shop") == 0)
{
    string = "rubber shoes";
} 
else 
{
    string = "other";
}
document.getElementById('static_block').innerHTML = string;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI the correct Magento way to do this in multi-store is to create 2 static block with the same ID and assign each one to the store view you want it to show on.   Magento will load the correct version based on the current store being viewed.